# Send html code to view in Sails JS?

Tags: sails.js

I use `Sails JS` and `Jade` template. In controller, I use `res.view('/index',{data:data});` to render index page with data. I want to send `html` code (ex: `<h1>DEMO TEST</h1>`) from controller to view. And How I must do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var htmlVar = '<h1>DEMO TEST</h1>'

return res.view('/index', {data : data, html : htmlVar})
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. My html code is appearing as html code on the page, rather than rendering.

Answer (score 0):

The standard output tag in EJS delivers HTML-escaped text:

```
<%= HTMLoutputVariable %>
```

This is the tag to use for non-escaped text:

```
<%- HTMLoutputVariable %>
```